# How to expose docker daemon metrics over HTTPS?

Tags: docker, prometheus, docker-daemon

[Docker daemon metrics](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-metrics) can be enabled by setting `dockerd` options:

```
OPTIONS="--experimental --metric-addr 127.0.0.1:9323"
```

The above can also be done by configuring `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. This would expose my metrics on `localhost:9323` over HTTP. I can access my metrics through `curl`, for example:

```sh
curl http://localhost:9323/metrics
```

However, I want to expose my docker daemon metrics over HTTPS to be scraped using Prometheus. Is there a way to do this?

I tried enabling TLS verification by setting the following flags: `--tls-verify`, `--tlscert`, `--tlskey` and `--tlscacert`, but this does not affect the metrics endpoint.

Comment: use a reverse proxy like nginx, [proxy_pass](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) etc

Comment: I guess that would be the most straight-forward solution.